# Escaping a dollar sign in bash -c cat command

Tags: bash, escaping, cat

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984960/escaping-a-dollar-sign-in-unix-inside-the-cat-command) not work in my case.
This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135708/escaping-dollar-sign-in-sh-c) is about **bash -c** but there is no cat example.

How Escaping a dollar sign using **bash -c** ?
This is my code. It is not work correct. I get empty file. But I want text **$6** in file.

```
bash -c "cat <<EOF > /home/pi/file.txt
\$6
EOF"
```

P.S. I need **bash -c** because I plan to use cat with sudo.

Comment: should be `bash -c "cat > /tmp/file" << EOF`

Comment: I guess "want $6" means that you want $6 be replaced by the 6th parameter of the calling function/script. In this case, don't escape it. If it is empty, then you don't have at least 6 parameters on the calling side.

Comment: @pynexj : I'm not convinced that your comment is correct. AFIK, just the next **word**  after << is taken as the delimiter for the here-document. Therefore it is safe to add another redirection (or even other parameters) after the <<EOF.

Comment: @pynexj : The lines in the HERE-Doc are bit intended for the command _bash_. They are intended as stdin for `cat`, i.e file `deleteFile` should be created having $6 as content. Basically the OP wants to achieve the effect of `echo "$6" >~/deleteFile` in a cumbersome way.

Comment: ok. i think OP should just use single quotes here. or use `\\\$6` for double quotes.

Comment: @pynexj \\\$6 works. Can you explain why I need 3 times back slash, not once? And what you mean "should just use single quotes here"? Give example please

Comment: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwb6T.png

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Probably you are looking for something like `printf '%s\n' '$6' 'foo' 'bar' 'baz' | sudo tee /path/to/file >/dev/null`